# How to combine add and edit method in java?

Tags: java, spring, addition, edit

I currently have separate add and edit methods but would like to combine them into one.

I think there should be a condition at the start of the method to determine if the object already exists or if it needs to be created, but I'm a beginner and I don't really know how to do it.

Add method :

```
public PatientEntity addPatient(PatientEntity patient) throws InvalidObjectException {
        checkPatient(patient);
        patientRepository.save(patient);

        return patient;
    }
```

Edit method :

```
public PatientEntity editPatient(int id, PatientEntity patient) throws InvalidObjectException, NoSuchElementException {
        checkPatient(patient);
        try {
            PatientEntity patientToEdit = this.findPatientById(id);

            patientToEdit.setName(patient.getName());
            patientToEdit.setCountry(patient.getCountry());
            patientToEdit.setGender(patient.getGender());
            patientToEdit.setPhone(patient.getPhone());

            patientRepository.save(patientToEdit);

            return patientToEdit;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your entity has the id inside you can check for it and if is not null you can do the update

```
public PatientEntity savePatient(PatientEntity patient) throws InvalidObjectException, NoSuchElementException {
    checkPatient(patient);
    
    if(patient.getId()==null){      
        patientRepository.save(patient);
        return patient;
    }else{  
        try {
            PatientEntity patientToEdit = this.findPatientById(id);

            patientToEdit.setName(patient.getName());
            patientToEdit.setCountry(patient.getCountry());
            patientToEdit.setGender(patient.getGender());
            patientToEdit.setPhone(patient.getPhone());

            patientRepository.save(patientToEdit);

            return patientToEdit;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

another solution is that the findPatientById method provide a new entity

```
PatientEntity findPatientById(int id) {
    if(id==null){
        return new PatientEntity();
    }else{
        // here the previous code to search on db
    }
}
```

and then you can use the editPatient method using a null id